# Regex doesn't give me expected result

Tags: c#, regex

Okay, I give up - time to call upon the regex gurus for some help.

I'm trying to validate CSV file contents, just to see if it looks like the expected valid CSV data. I'm not trying to validate all possible CSV forms, just that it "looks like" CSV data and isn't binary data, a code file or whatever.

Each line of data comprises comma-separated words, each word comprising `a-z`, `0-9`, and a small number of of punctuation chars, namely `-` and `_`. There may be several lines in the file. That's it.

Here's my simple code:

```
const string dataWord = @"[a-z0-9_\-]+";
const string dataLine = "("+dataWord+@"\s*,\s*)*"+dataWord;
const string csvDataFormat = "("+dataLine+") |  (("+dataLine+@"\r\n)*"+dataLine +")";

Regex validCSVDataPattern = new Regex(csvDataFormat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
protected override bool IsCorrectDataFormat(string fileContents)
{
    return validCSVDataPattern.IsMatch(fileContents);
}
```

This gives me a regex pattern of

```
(([a-z0-9_\-]+\s*,\s*)*[a-z0-9_\-]+) |  ((([a-z0-9_\-]+\s*,\s*)*[a-z0-9_\-]+\r\n)*([a-z0-9_\-]+\s*,\s*)*[a-z0-9_\-]+)
```

However if I present this with a block of, say, C# code, the regex parser says it is a match. How is that? the C# code doesn't look anything like my CSV pattern (it has punctuation other than `_` and `-`, for a start).

Can anyone point out my obvious error? Let me repeat - I am not trying to validate all possible CSV forms, just my simple subset.

Comment: can you add an example line that should work and one that shouldn't?

Comment: I'm not sure how this test (if it worked) is different from just checking that the file contains only the allowed characters: `^[0-9a-zA-Z\s,_-]*$`. Except that your pattern doesn't permit empty fields, which can generally be part of CSV files. Also note that the second alternative in your `csvDataFormat` pattern includes the first one.

Comment: Note that the comma forces your regex to match at least two values per line. If only one value per line is fine, change it to this `dataLine = dataWord+@"(\s*,\s*"+dataWord+")*";`

Comment: Example data:

abc,abc , ac_c

or

abc,abc,,ac_c

and possibly multiple similar lines, and possibly more 'words' on each line, but always a few never one.


Not permitted:

using System;
//some code goes here

Comment: @haughtonomous if `ab,,c,df` is valid, then change to `dataWord = @"[a-z0-9_\-]*"`

Comment: That's a good pointer - I hadn't yet considered the empty field possibility - but it doens't solve my root problem.

Comment: Note that some extra backslashes were introduced when the question was reformatted.  You probably added them to prevent SO eating the "real" backslash in `[a-z0-9_\-]`.  I fixed that, but you didn't really need to escape that hyphen in the first place; `-` matches a literal `-` if it's the first or last character listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better pattern which looks for CSV groups such as `XXX,` or `yyy` for one to many in each line:

```
^([\w\s_\-]*,?)+$
```

`^`             - Start of each line

`(`             - a CSV match group start

`[\w\s_\-]*` - Valid characters `\w (a-zA-Z0-9)` and `_` and `-` in each CSV

`,?`             - maybe a comma

`)+`             - End of the csv match group, 1 to many of these expected.

That will validate a whole file, line by line for a basic CSV structure and allow for empty `,,` situations.

Comment: Note that `\w` matches much more than just `a-zA-Z0-9` in .NET.

Comment: It works! Thanks, and thanks to everyone else who contributed.

Comment: @haughtonomous yes one has to escape the dash character because in a set [ ] it denominates a range such as [a-z]. So escaping it tells the parser to treat it as a character in a set; hence what we want, an allowed character in the set.

Comment: Alan Moore (comment to previous answer in this thread) thinks not ("- matches a literal - if it's the first or last character listed.") I've escaped mine in order to be sure.

Comment: @haughtonomous I believe Alan is correct. :-) I will go this though, if one ever updates the set and accidently places another character after the -, it becomes a defacto range. So escaping it will ensure it is always treated as a literal by the regex pattern parser.

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression is missing the `^` (beginning of line) and `$` (end of line) anchors. This means that it would match any text that *contains* what is described by the expression, even if the text contains other completely unrelated parts.

For example, this text matches the expression:

```
foo, bar
```

and therefore this text also matches:

```
var result = calculate(foo, bar);
```

You can see where this is going.

Add `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of `csvDataFormat` to get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid that causes valid data to fail. There are two optional parts to the pattern. If I sandwich both of them in ^ and $ the legitimate content fails as well, and if I precede the first option with ^ and end the second with $, both legitimate and not legitimate data passes.

Comment: @haughtonomous: It would be helpful to update the question with more specific information. I tried this regex with this input, it failed but I expected success, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this regex:

```
^([a-z0-9_\-]+)(\s*)(,\s*[a-z0-9_\-]+)*$
```

Tests

```
asbc_- ,   khkhkjh,    lkjlkjlkj_-,     j : PASS
asbc,                                     : FAIL
asbc_-,khkhkjh,lkjlkjlk909j_-,j           : PASS
```

If you want to match empty lines like `,,,` or  when some values are blank like `,abcd,,` use

```
^([a-z0-9_\-]*)(\s*)(,\s*[a-z0-9_\-]*)*$
```

Loop through all the lines to see if the file is ok:

```
const string dataLine = "^([a-z0-9_\-]+)(\s*)(,\s*[a-z0-9_\-]+)*$";
Regex validCSVDataPattern = new Regex(csvDataFormat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
protected override bool IsCorrectDataFormat(string fileContents)
{
    string[] lines = fileContents.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (!validCSVDataPattern.IsMatch(line))
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Will that handle multiple lines?

Comment: No, it will check only one line. You will have to loop through each line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@"(?in)^[a-z0-9_-]+( *, *[a-z0-9_-]+)*([\r\n]+[a-z0-9_-]+( *, *[a-z0-9_-]+)*)*$"
```

The noteworthy changes are:

- Added anchors (`^` and `$`, because the regex is totally pointless without them
- Removed spaces (which have to match literal spaces, and I don't think that's what you intended)
- Replaced the `\s` in every occurrence of `\s*` with a literal space (because `\s` can match any whitespace character, and you only want to match actual spaces in those spots)

The basic structure of your regex looked pretty good until that `|` came along and bollixed things up. ;)

p.s., In case you're wondering, `(?in)` is an inline modifier that sets `IgnoreCase` and `ExplicitCapture` modes.