# Regex to match comma separated list with no comma on the end

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a .Net (C#) Regex to match a comma separated list of numbers that will not match if there is a comma as the last character

```
123,123,123,123 true - correct match
123,123,123,123, false - comma on end 
123,123,123,,123 false - double comma
,123,123,123,123 false - comma at start
"" false - empty string

123 true - single value
```

I have found this Regex but matches when there is a comma on the end `^([0-9]+,?)+$`

What would be a Regex pattern that would fit this pattern?

**EDIT:** Added 1 example for clarity the correct answer works for `123`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

```
^([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+$
```

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5B0-9%5D%2b,%29*%5B0-9%5D%2b$&input=123,123,123,123%0A123,123,123,123,%0A123,123,123,,123%0A,123,123,123,123%0A%0A).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
//This regex was provided before the question was edited to say that
//a single number is valid.
^((\d+\s*,\s*)+(\s*)(\d+))$

//In case a single number is valid
^(\d+)(\s*)(,\s*\d+)*$
```

Here are the test results

```
 123,123,123,123    match
 123,123,123,123,   no match 
 123,123,123,,123   no match
 ,123,123,123,123   no match
 ""                 no match (empty string)
 123                no match for the first regex, match for the second one
```

See [Regex doesn't give me expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195766/regex-doesnt-give-me-expected-result/17195956#17195956)

Edit: Modified the regex to include the last case of a single number without any comma.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

No postfix/prefix commas: `[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*`

No prefix (optional postfix): `[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*,?`

No postfix (optional prefix): `,?[0-9]+(,[0-9])*`

Optional postfix and prefix: `,?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*,?`